# Forest Plot: Proportions on x axis

Tags: meta-analysis

In most descriptions of Forest Plots the x-axis is an Odds Ratio or a Difference of means etc.

But I'm now reading a paper where the x-axis is labeled "Proportion" with the scale going from 0 to 0.8. How does one interpret this?

The scale is linear, and not log. OR scales are typically log?

The authors report they've used MedCalc  for the analysis & the plot looks like something a canned, out-of-the-box routine in the software produced.

https://www.medcalc.org/

**Edit:** They call the plots "Forest plots of proportions of disease response rates".  My guess is that their x-axis quantity is something like the proportion of subjects that showed "improvement" or response to the intervention.

But I'd love any comments.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are used to looking at meta-analyses of comparative primary studies but this is a meta-analysis of non-comparative studies so the authors are meta-analysing the proportion of some quantity. Note that the proportions have confidence intervals which are not symmetrical on the scale shown. Whether the software (or the authors) transformed the proportions is not something we can tell from what you give us but it would be usual to do so. There are many possible transformations: log, logit, arcsine square root, Freeman-Tukey, ...

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of any good articles / sites that describe the interpretation and details of a Forest Plot of non-comparative studies?  All the tutorials etc. I came across seem to not explain this type.

Comment: Re. the transformation of the proportions: The paper itself is mum on it but digging deeper into the statistical package's manual reveals that: "MedCalc uses a Freeman-Tukey transformation (arcsine square root transformation; Freeman and Tukey, 1950) to calculate the weighted summary Proportion under the fixed and random effects model (DerSimonian & Laird, 1986)."

Comment: You could look at http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses#meta-analysis_of_proportions which has a couple of references, one of which you already have.